# JSFiddle API examples are broken

Tags: javascript, highcharts

From the API documentation in:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.alignTicks

Clicking in align ticks true example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/alignticks-true/

Doesn't render the chart. The following error appears in the JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'
```

Answer (score 3):

problem is .highchart. Use

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        //alignTicks: false,
        type: 'line',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    ...
}
```

problem is HighCharts js file updates. In highcharts offical site demos are not working , too.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alirizaadiyahsi_44/LLExL/1107/)

Comment: Just contacted their support team by email, so they can fix the problem ASAP. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The .highcharts mechanism was introduced in Highcharts 3.0 via a JQuery plugin, as documented in the [Highcharts 3.0 release announcement](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/54-highcharts-3-0-released).  Presumably the JSFiddle pages in question that weren't working were including an older version of Highcharts at the time, as I was until I figured why my own charts weren't working!

Answer (score 1):

I updated their [jsfiddle chart](http://jsfiddle.net/wsdookadr/HzJUt/1/).

It works now. The problem was with `highcharts` which didn't really existed as a method of the jQuery object.